# Fastest way to search value in a python dictionaries containing arrays

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary of below format :

```
{'Company': [{'doc': 'Apple', 'applicable_for': None, 'is_default': 0}, {'doc': 'Microsoft', 'applicable_for': None, 'is_default': False}], 'Branch': [{'doc': 'California', 'applicable_for': None, 'is_default': 0}, {'doc': 'Boston', 'applicable_for': None, 'is_default': False}]}
```

What is the best way to know if "Apple" exist inside key "company".

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast if you return as soon as possible:

```py
def has_apple(d):
    for company in d["company"]:
        if(company["doc"] == "apple"):
           return True
    return False
```

This returns true just after found the company without iterating further

Answer (score 0):

```
"Apple" in [x["doc"] for x in d["Company"]]
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for why this solves the problem? Code only answers make it harder for future users to locate solutions.